# Facebook login crashes the android APP in React native

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, react-native

I am trying to implement facebook login in my app but it's crashing the app on hitting the login button or calling it through the Login Manager. I followed, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current step by step.

Here is a complete implementations - https://github.com/sanbornsen/rct-fblogin-test

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to run the app from Android Studio? It should print all the messages to the log so you can see exactly what is going on. It might not necessarily be related to the FB package but something being undefined or what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-publishing actions, you need to use 'readPermissions' instead on line 59 in index.android.js.

```
readPermissions={['public_profile']}
```